I am not able to detect/connect bluetooth device using service UUID in iOS however same device able to detect/connect in android and share the data
I am not able to connect bluetooth device using service UUID and read and write characteristics  in iOS however same device able to connect in android and share the data
Below are the Service UUID and read and write characteristics
type here
Servie UUID 0000FD00-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB 

Read UUID 0000FD03-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB

class BluetoothManager: NSObject, CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate {
    var centralManager: CBCentralManager!
    var peripheralDevice: CBPeripheral?
    var eSIMCharacteristic: CBCharacteristic?

    // UUIDs for the custom service and characteristic
    let eSIMServiceUUID = CBUUID(string: "0000FD00-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB")

override init() {
        super.init()
        // Initialize the CBCentralManager
        centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
    }

    // Central Manager state change (check if Bluetooth is available)
    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
        if central.state == .poweredOn {
            // Start scanning for the charging box
            centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: [eSIMServiceUUID], options: [CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey: true])
}

 // Discovered a peripheral (charging box)
    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
        print("peripheral", peripheral, peripheral.identifier)
        // Stop scanning and connect to the peripheral
       centralManager.stopScan()
      peripheralDevice = peripheral
       peripheralDevice?.delegate = self
        centralManager.connect(peripheral, options: nil)
    }

    // Connected to the peripheral (charging box)
    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
        // Discover services on the peripheral
        print("Connected to device: \(peripheral.name ?? "Unknown")")
        peripheral.discoverServices([eSIMServiceUUID])
    }

    // Discovered services on the peripheral
    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: Error?) {
        print("error occured", error)
    }

This is my code for connecting the device however I am able to detect the device or not getting error also

You need to provide the code you're using to connect on iOS, as well as how you're requesting system permissions, and the actual symptoms you're seeings. What odes "not able" mean in this case? The device is not discovered at all? The device is discovered but has the wrong services? The device has the right services, but you cannot connect? There's an error? There's no error? You need to explain what you're doing, what you expect to occur, and what does occur.

Hi @RobNapier, Thanks for your reply . I have updated my code please check once and appreciate your support

By "I am able to detect the device" you mean that the print("peripheral", peripheral, peripheral.identifier) line runs? And by "I am not able to connect" you mean print("Connected to device: \(peripheral.name ?? "Unknown")") never runs, and you never get an error, and nothing happens for at least a minute? Or do you mean something else? You need to be specific about what you do and what happens. "I am able to detect the device" does not tell use what is happening. There is no step called "detect" in BLE or in your code.

Hi @RobNapier, I am not able to detect the device using the service Id provides .. no of the methods are getting called and this method never runs
"print("Connected to device: (peripheral.name ?? "Unknown")")"
If you have ever worked Bluetooth framework this is the method to scan / detect the  Bluetooth devices
"centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: [eSIMServiceUUID], options: [CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey: true])"
one more thing for better understanding I am not getting any error also which means "didDiscoverServices" this method also not calling

Given the updated comments where you explain that you are not discovering the device, the likely issue is your UUID:
let eSIMServiceUUID = CBUUID(string: "0000FD00-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB")

This is actually an unassigned 16-bit UUID that your application seems to be squatting on (using without having it assigned to you). This is not supported and breaks spec, but can work if you're lucky. But generally you need to express it in the 16-bit form:
let eSIMServiceUUID = CBUUID(string: "FD00")

That should work better at discovering the device. 16-bit UUIDs are advertised in a different payload than 128-bit.
If it doesn't, then scan for nil and see what service is actually being advertised.

Hi Rob Napier,
Thanks for your reply .
I have let eSIMServiceUUID = CBUUID(string: "FD00") this one still not able to find any peripheral If I pass nil I can see some devices except the device I am looking for
Please find below for nil

You'll need to check with known-good scanners like nRF Connect or LightBlue. If they can see it and you can't, you have a bug in your app. If they can't see it, the device is probably advertising incorrectly.
